# C++ mechanism of constructing, deconstructing and pointer to class object

Tags: c++

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class A
{
private:
   int m_i;
   friend int main(int argc, char const *argv[]);
public:
   A (int i = 0):m_i(i){};
   void display()
   {
       cout << m_i << endl;
   }
   int result() {return m_i;}
};

void createA(A *pa)
{
   pa = new A(1);
}

A* createA()
{
   A a(2);
   return &a;
}

void createAonstack()
{
   A a(3);
}

int main(int argc, char const *argv[])
{
   A a;
   A * pa = &a;
   pa->display();
   createA(pa);
   pa->display();

   A * a2 = createA();
   cout << a2->m_i << endl;
   createAonstack();
   cout << a2->m_i << endl;
   return 0;
}
```

The results of the program above is

```
0
0
2
3
```

How to explain the result 2 and 3? From my understanding, the object created in function `createA()` should be deconstructed, and the pointer it returns should point to `NULL`, but why `a2->m_i` can be 2. And the 3 is even more confusing, as it seems that the function `createAonstack()` has nothing to do with a2.

Comment: Looks like undefined behavior

Comment: _'as it seems that the function createAonstack() has nothing to do with a2'_ Why are you expecting it should?!?

Comment: First thing first: activate warnings and act on them. `createA` should generate a warning that you are returning a reference to a local object.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You said

> From my understanding, the object created in function `createA()` should be deconstructed, and the pointer it returns should point to `NULL`, but why `a2->m_i` can be `2`.

It is true that

> the object created in function `createA()` should be deconstructed

It is not true that

> and the pointer it returns should point to `NULL`

The pointer returned by `createA` is non-NULL even though it is an invalid pointer to use in the calling function.

> but why `a2->m_i` can be `2`.

It's pure coincidence. It really is undefined behavior. Anything can happen when you dereference `a2`.

Comment: So can I put this in this way: the object is deconstructed, but the data the pointer pointing to has not been but open to rewritten?

Comment: @ryecao, that's the behavior you are observing in your run time environment. A different environment, even using different compiler options in your environment, is likely to exhibit different behavior.

Answer (score 1):

Function `createA()` returns a pointer on a local variable, that is destroyed at quitting the function, so anything can happen,  direct crash, or worse, the program will work as if everything is ok.

As Bjarne Stroustrup said: `C makes it easy to shoot yourself in the foot; C++ makes it harder, but when you do it blows your whole leg off.`

Answer (score 0):

As a quick tip, some more differentiable naming conventions might help readability in the future, as I personally find it a little hard to follow.

However, from what I can tell, it's a scoping problem. CreateA() produces a local pointer, and when it leaves that function's scope, it's lost. So whatever you're actually accessing is essentially random.